# FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but services/p0dnjzr7HZrcp6Mifiqh has 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code

```
    getPostInfo(id: string) {
      const Post = this.afStore.collection(`services/${id}`)
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          switchMap(services => {
            const res = services
            .map((service: Service) => {
              return this.afStore.doc<UserModel>(`users/${service.userId}`)
              .valueChanges()
              .pipe(
                map(user => Object.assign(service, { user }))
              );
            });
            return combineLatest([...res]);
          })
        );
      return Post;
    }
```

I even tried
`const Post = this.afStore.collection('services').doc(id)`
But I get this error :

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing this

```
return this.afStore.collection(`services`).doc(id)
```

into

```
return this.afStore.collection('services', ref => ref.where('id', '==', id))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a direct path to your document. This approach works with Real Time DB but not with Cloud FireStore.

Proper way will be:

```
this.afStore.collection('services').doc(id).valueChanges()...
```

You also should consider that you won't get your Post details immediately because it's asynchronous.

The final result should look something like this:

```
getPostInfo(id: string): Observable<T> {
  return this.afStore.collection(`services`).doc(id)
   .valueChanges()
   .pipe(
     switchMap(services => {
       const res = services
        .map((service: Service) => {
          return this.afStore.doc<UserModel>(`users/${service.userId}`)
            .valueChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(user => Object.assign(service, { user }))
            );
         });
       return combineLatest([...res]);
    })
  );
```

And then you'll need to subscribe to your getPostInfo

`this.getPostInfo(id).subscribe((res) => console.log(res));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still having an issue with "map" Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)